# Lemon and Mint drink

Tags: drinks, mint, lemon

I once had a delicious lemon and mint drink on a flight with Qatar airways, but I have no idea what it was or how it might have been made. Does anyone know what it might have been and how it was made?

**Edit**

I'm not sure if it was made on board or not. It wasn't carbonated but it was chilled when it was served. It did have a slight syrupy consistency like there might have been some sugar syrup in it. There wasn't any alcohol in it and I couldn't make out any other flavours.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a lovely middle-eastern recipe for mint lemonade.
I used to make loads of this stuff in my navy days.
So, for a jug serving six sailors:

- Juice of about 2-3 lemons
- Six tablespoons of sugar
- nice handful of mint

Put the mint and sugar in the jug and pour about half a cup of boiling water. 
Stir well, and leave for a few minutes so that the mint can think about what it has done.
Add lemon juice and water slowly while stirring.

The amounts may not be precise, as I used to make this in an eight gallon saucepan, and these days I make it in a 2-cup shaker.

Answer (score 5):

**Middle Eastern Lemonade**

Serves 6

- 8 lemons
- 3/4 cup sugar, or to taste
- 1 teaspoon orange blossom water, or to taste
- generous 1/4 cup freshly chopped mint
- water (or seltzer) and ice cubes

Is this what you're looking for maybe?

Answer (score 2):

I just flew yesterday and asked what it was.  They make it with sprite instead of making the stuff. So lemons, mint, and I think she said bitters.